# Is it possible to share a file with Intent.ACTION_SEND retrieve and store users choice

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I would like to allow user to share a file let's say with `Intent.ACTION_SEND` then store users choice and address/phone number in order to be able to automatically send a different file to the same destination at a different time. Is this possible and how?
Thanks

Comment: It is most certainly possible.

Comment: and could you at least lead me in the right direction. Over an hour of research did not lead me to anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can share your file as Binary data as explained below.

Referenced Link from Android Developer Page:
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

> Send Binary Content
>
> Binary data is shared using the ACTION_SEND action combined with
>   setting the appropriate MIME type and placing the URI to the data in
>   an extra named EXTRA_STREAM. This is commonly used to share an image
>   but can be used to share any type of binary content:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

> Note the following:
>
> You can use a MIME type of "*/*", but this will only match activities
>   that are able to handle generic data streams. The receiving
>   application needs permission to access the data the Uri points to. The
>   recommended ways to do this are: Store the data in your own
>   ContentProvider, making sure that other apps have the correct
>   permission to access your provider. The preferred mechanism for
>   providing access is to use per-URI permissions which are temporary and
>   only grant access to the receiving application. An easy way to create
>   a ContentProvider like this is to use the FileProvider helper class.
>   Use the system MediaStore. The MediaStore is primarily aimed at video,
>   audio and image MIME types, however beginning with Android 3.0 (API
>   level 11) it can also store non-media types (see MediaStore.Files for
>   more info). Files can be inserted into the MediaStore using scanFile()
>   after which a content:// style Uri suitable for sharing is passed to
>   the provided onScanCompleted() callback. Note that once added to the
>   system MediaStore the content is accessible to any app on the device

Just change the last line in above code, so that it won't show chooser everytime. It will store the default choice in subsequent run of your application.

```
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Regarding "*then store users choice and address/phone number in order to be able to automatically send a different file to the same destination*"

User choice of sending your file to a particular application will be stored by using above code. But I don't think so you can store particular number/address from another application in your application, for sending files subsequently. Once your intent goes to another activity (application), it can not be controlled from your previous activity (application). Each time, you have to select that particular address/numer in second application.

Comment: Thanks, I did not mean to limit myself to the sending Intent mechanism. Is there any other way?

Comment: I can't think of any other mechanism as of now. Intent is the standard way to go. Let's see if someone else suggests something. If you find any other alternative please share here.